# Exception Thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in C# Windows Service When Entity Data Model Object Instantiated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-express, windows-server-2012

Running on **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard** is a **C# Windows Service (.Net Framework 4.7.2)** using **Entity Framework** that I wrote which reads data from a file and passes the data to a **local SQLExpress (2016)** stored procedure to insert the data into the DB.

While testing on my Windows 10 machine it works fine, but after moving the executable and exe.config to the Windows Server and updating the config with the correct DB information in the connection string, the Event Viewer shows the following Windows Application Error:

Source: .NET Runtime Event 1026

```
Application: Print_Mail-DBAuger.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at Print_Mail_DBAuger.Program.StartParseAndInsert(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLog)
   at Print_Mail_DBAuger.FetchService.OnChanged(System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

This seems to be preventing the stored procedure from being called, so no data is being passed to the DB.

I have narrowed the issue down to the instantiation of the Entity Data Model object:

```
PrintMailEntities dataEntities = new PrintMailEntities();
```

This line calls auto-generated code created by the Entity Framework:

```
public partial class PrintMailEntities : DbContext
    {
        public PrintMailEntities()
            : base("name=PrintMailEntities")
        {
        }
        
        // Several more auto-generated methods...
    }
```

And the super class constructor (again, part of the Entity Framework, not my code):

```
public class DbContext : IDisposable, IObjectContextAdapter
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection
        //     string for the database to which a connection will be made. See the class remarks
        //     for how this is used to create a connection.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   nameOrConnectionString:
        //     Either the database name or a connection string.
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope")]
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString);

        // Other overrloaded constructors not used...
     }
```

Everything in the program prior to this line works as desired (I used several application event logs to track what was happening since I don't have Visual Studio on the Windows Server to debug with.) **The file I am trying to read from is not the issue, I can read that information fine.**

I have also tried surrounding the instantiation with a try/catch to catch the FileNotFoundException, but the catch is never fired. I have also mirrored the database permissions of the Windows Server DB to match that of my local machines DB, and running both with admin privileges.

Here is the connection string in the Windows Server exe.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="PrintMailEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=machineName\HPWJA;initial catalog=PrintMail;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Again, this works fine on Windows 10 with the connection string pointed to a DB that mirrors the Windows Server DB. There are no build errors on my machine, and there are no SQL Server Logs on the Windows Server stating that anything wrong is happening on the DB side.

**EDIT**

Thanks to RB I now have more details about this "file" that couldn't be found. Here is the updated event log.

```
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Print_Mail_DBAuger.Program.StartParseAndInsert(String inputFile, EventLog programEventLog)
   at Print_Mail_DBAuger.FetchService.OnChanged(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 was missing.
```

The error seems to be referencing a section element in app.config

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

The server does not have internet, so maybe it's trying to pull the nuget package from online?

Comment: The issue is in the call stack.
- Program.StartParseAndInsert(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLog)
- FetchService.OnChanged(System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
A Windows Service has a base directory of C:\Windows if I remember correctly, whatever the path of your .exe is. So if you try to load a file with a relative path, this may fail.

Comment: Hazrelle, the rest of the executable up until the point of the Entity Data Model object instantiation is working fine though. And the service property "Path to executable" is an absolute path. Am I missing something? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Put a `try...catch(FileNotFoundException e)...` around the whole of the `StartParaeAndInsert` method. Log out the name of the file that could not be found. You will have the answer to your issue then.

Comment: Looks like you are using a FileWatcher, do you have a delay between when the file arrives and when you try to read it? I've run into this before, it's because the event fires as soon as the file is created but the process that created it is still writing to it and has a lock on it when it attempts to read it. This typically doesn't show up when testing on your machine since files are usually smaller and local as opposed to being bigger and being written across the network. A few hundred milliseconds is generally enough.

Comment: bschellekens, Yes I am using a FileWatcher, but no that is not the issue. The file I am reading works just fine (I have a class for handling locked files). It has nothing to do with the FileWatcher, it is just the Entity object instantiation. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Its nothing to do with EF, its everything to do with it can find <insert what ever file here>

Comment: TheGeneral, everything to do with what EF can find? Is this what you mean?

Comment: This has nothing to with entities, models, instantiation, entity framework, or anything. Some file you are looking for is not there... that is it. Likely moved, after you have the signal from the FileWatcher

Comment: So if it has nothing to do with EF, why would instantiating the EF object throw the exception? Because remove that line and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Look at the stack trace! It tells you the exact method that's throwing. The exception tells you exactly what is wrong. Put a try...catch around it like I said earlier and find out what the missing file is (there is a property `Filename` on the exception)! Whatever else you are doing is a red herring - believe the exception, and believe stack trace, they do not lie! Also, this will take 2 minutes to check, so it's really not worth discussing - easier to just do it, and report back the results :)

Comment: RB, yes I believe you and yes I am going to try it, the server is just unavailable at the moment lol I am waiting for it to be ready again to try what you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: RB, so that try/catch did work (I don't know why it didn't work when I surrounded just the object instantiation, because that's all that the method StartParseAndInsert is doing). But anyway, I did get the log from it, and it looks like it is an issue with EF. Will edit the original post to show the new log. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so the error is complaining that it cannot find the EntiryFramework dll. Did you definitely copy it over with the rest of the application? Are you definitely using EF 6? Note that you can use [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to see *exactly* where Fusion (the .NET Framework assembly binder) is looking for that dll - that might give you a good clue what is going on.

Comment: (I note that you said you moved "the executable and exe config" - this implies you have *not* moved the dependent DLLs like Entity Framework. Any dll that is not present will cause a FileNotFoundException when fusion attempts to load it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was missing the EntityFramework.dll found in the Release directory of the build output. Adding both EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll solved this issue. Thanks RB for helping me find this.